# Trying to implement Google's "did you mean" feature in java

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to implement google's "did you mean" feature in java.
I found some code on internet saying it works properly, it gets me an error though when trying to run it. I think it has to do with the directory creation, which is the only part of the code I do not exactly understand.

Here is the code, could you give me some help on what's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
             public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
             File dir = new File("C:/Users/Lala");
             Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(dir);

             SpellChecker spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);

             spellChecker.indexDictionary(
             new PlainTextDictionary(new File("fulldictionary00.txt")));
             String wordForSuggestions = "hwllo";
             int suggestionsNumber = 5;
             String[] suggestions = spellChecker.
                 suggestSimilar(wordForSuggestions, suggestionsNumber);
             if (suggestions!=null && suggestions.length>0) {
                 for (String word : suggestions) {
                     System.out.println("Did you mean:" + word);
                 }
             }
             else {
                 System.out.println("No suggestions found for word:"+wordForSuggestions);
             }

         }
```

The file `fulldictionary00.txt` is a plain text file in the right format.

The error I get though is at line 18:

```
SpellChecker spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);
```

so it has to do with the directory creation.. I am pasting the error I get just in case any idea accures when you see it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/document/Fieldable at did_you_mean.main(did_you_mean.java:18) Caused by:     
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case that someone else has the same problem,  I found a way to solve it!

First of all, the problem seemed to be at version 4.0.0 of lucene, the one that I downloaded, because a class of a jar file was calling a class in another jar file that had been renamed in this version.

To fix the problem I just downloaded an older version (3.6.1), which demanded some changes to the existing code. In this version, spellChecker.IndexDictionary() function needs 3 arguments:

`spellChecker.indexDictionary(new PlainTextDictionary(new File("fulldictionary00.txt")),config,false);`

config is an IndexWriterConfig object.

I hope this'll help someone with the same problem!
@ppeterka thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

well,In lucene 4.0.0, spellchecker is put in a package named lucene-suggest-4.0.0.jar rather than lucene-spellchecker-XXX.jar

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

As per OPs comment though, the error is that the JAR file of Lucene does not seem to be on the class path...

*Original answer, without knowing about the error (might be useful to leave it here as it is)*

You have to add content into the file specified... It doesn't work without that. Just do a bit of thinking: how should the program know which words are correct and which are not?

For your case of plain text dictionary file, you should use **[PlainTextDictionary](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/api/contrib-spellchecker/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/PlainTextDictionary.html)**

> Dictionary represented by a text file.
>
> Format allowed: 1 word per line:
>   word1
>   word2
>   word3

[This page](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/SpellChecker) explains it a bit in context of a Lucene index:

> Import: Adding Words to the Dictionary
>   We can add the words coming from a Lucene Index (more precisely from a set of Lucene fields), and from a text file with a list of words.
>
> Example: we can add all the keywords of a given Lucene field of my index.

```
SpellChecker spell= new SpellChecker(dictionaryDirectory);
spell.indexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(my_luceneReader,my_fieldname));
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer!
fulldictionary00.txt is a dictionary in the format you just mentioned, sorry for not saying that earlier.
The error i get though is at line 18(SpellChecker spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);) , so it has to do with the directory creation..

I am pasting the error I get just in case any idea accures when you see it.
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/document/Fieldable
 at did_you_mean.main(did_you_mean.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable`

Comment: @missrg: how do you run your application? Is the Lucene JAR file included in the runtime configuration?

Comment: Yeah, I think I have included everything necessary for the program.
Take a look yourself:

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.lucene.search.spell.PlainTextDictionary;
import org.apache.lucene.search.spell.SpellChecker;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

Comment: @missrg And how do you start the program?

Comment: The whole program is what you see in main (plus the includes), no more code lines. I run it from eclipse with the run button..

Comment: @missrg in the Debug (or Run) configurations, on the `Classpath` tab, what do you see, is the lucene-core.jar there?

Comment: Yes it's there.. 
Actually that's what i was checking right now, because i was reading an article saying what this error is about.
Do you think that there is any possibility that the lucene-core.jar version that i have downloaded is wrong or misses some classes?
I don't know what else to think...